# Cocos2d-js: How to exit an application in Android and Ios?

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I like to know how to exit an app in a good way in Android and Ios?

In the helloworld app of cocos2d-js this code is unfortunately omitted:

```
    var closeItem = cc.MenuItemImage.create(
            res.CloseNormal_png,
            res.CloseSelected_png,
            function () {
                cc.log("Menu is clicked!");
            }, this);
```

What can be there instead of

```
cc.log("Menu is clicked!");
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Android, you should call `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();` to end the app. For Apple though, you could call `exit(0)` but its not really recommended to exit apps and will appear sort of like a crash. Do you need a close button? Most apps don't tend to have them and just keep running until the system or the user kills them.